# using argument end=" " for print function in Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following code:

```
i=0
while i<5:
    print(i, end=" ")
    i = i + 1
```

which results in the output:

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

if i want to add a string "the result" before 1 2 3 4, output expected: the result 1 2 3 4 (on same line). What built in function should I use?

Comment: do you mean - `result 0 1 2 3 4`?

Comment: Yes. Exactly what i mean

Comment: You should use `print`, before the loop.

Comment: @larsmans Could you please post that as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
i = 0
print('the result', end=' ') # begin line with 'the result'
while i < 5:
    print(i, end=' ')
    i = i + 1
print()  # move to next line
```