# How to do ghost-like typist in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, console

I'm a beginner, how can I do ghost-like typist in console?

**EDIT:**

I did something like this, just prints a letter per line:

```
def ghostPrint(sentence):
    for letter in sentence:
        time.sleep(0.12)
        print (letter)

ghostPrint("Hello world...")
```

This one, just changes letter in the same line:

```
def ghostPrint(sentence):
    for letter in sentence:
        time.sleep(0.12)
        print (letter, end="\r")

ghostPrint("Hello world...")
```

And this one, prints `Hello World...` then closes:

```
def ghostPrint(sentence):
    for letter in sentence:
        time.sleep(0.12)
        print (letter, end = " ")

ghostPrint("Hello world...")
```

I am currently using Python 3.5.

Comment: If this is Python 3 (as suggested by the print function), try using the `end` argument to `print()`. See for example other SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858219/using-argument-end-for-print-function-in-python-3-3

Comment: How'bout using `end=""`?

Comment: That's the ghost in your computer that changed the title: your script is working.

Comment: please post a complete answer

Comment: You have both an answer and a comment that solves your problem. What consitutes a complete answer for you?

Comment: still doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @cromic I will not work if we use `end=""`  as it every thing at once

Comment: @cromix your question is vary valid on  `python 3.x`

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, a trailing comma after a `print` statement will suppress the newline (it also adds a space between the arguments to print). So

```
print var1, var2,
```

prints the values of `var1` and `var2` with a space in between, and does not print a trailing newline.

In Python 3, the `print` function takes two arguments, `sep` and `end`. The default values are `sep=' '` and `end='\n'`. Use `sep` to change what string is used to separate arguments to `print`, and use `end` to change what string is printed after everything else.

Answer (score -1):

Use a trailing `comma(,)` to avoid a newline.

```
import time
def ghostPrint(sentence):
    for letter in sentence:
        time.sleep(0.12)
        print (letter),

ghostPrint("Hello world...")
```

In `python 3.x` using `print (letter,end='')` will not work I guesses as it print every thing at once.